# AJAX Call not working on some 3G providers

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I have an Android Phonegap Application that has some AJAX calls, they work over WiFi but not on 3G with some providers. I live in The Netherlands and its working on T-Mobile, but it isn't over Hi (dutch provider). I have an local jQuery file, but also tried an external one, both didn't work. I tested on Phonegap 1.5, 1.6 and 1.4.1 and not one of them is working.

The AJAX call is pretty basic:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL TO BE LOADED",
    type: 'post',
    data: "username="+gebruikersnaam,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I have no idea why it isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SDK is not allowing Ajax/Cross-domain requests. Trying to config [`$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; $.support.cors = true`

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Comment: But it's working just fine over WiFi and some 3G providers, so i don't think thats the problem.

Comment: I Have the same problem with my ajax call.  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; $.support.cors = true not solved my problem..